# Can't add attributes to classmethods

Tags: python

This following snippet will cause a `AttributeError: 'classmethod' object has no attribute 'val'`. Any idea why and how to work around this?

```
class App(object):
    @classmethod
    def cfn(kls, *args):
        print kls, args
    cfn.val = 10
```

Comment: That's not the error message it produces. It gives `AttributeError: 'classmethod' object has no attribute 'val'`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is probably a better way to do that

Comment: @user2357112 yep, just updated it.

Comment: @JBernardo I was trying to refactor the Django source code to use `@classmethod` instead of `meth = classmethod(meth)`, but [this method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L62) stopped me. And you're right, I finally left that alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class methods simply don't support adding arbitrary attributes to them. Your best bet is to take the data you were going to put in a class method attribute and stick it somewhere else.

Comment: Why classmethods dont support it? If I just comment that `@classmethod`, the code works fine.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Probably because no one wanted the feature enough to push it through. Also, if a class `Foo` has a class method `f`, `Foo.f` is a new bound method object generated on every access, so it's awkward to get at the actual `classmethod` instance.

Answer (score 3):

It actually is possible to add a custom attribute to your classmethod.

**NB tested on Python 3.4 only**

**TL;DR**

```
class classmethod_with_custom_attribute(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        wrapped_func.val = self.val
        wrapped_func = classmethod(wrapped_func)
        return wrapped_func

class App(object):
    @classmethod_with_custom_attribute(val=10)
    def cfn(cls, *args):
        print(cls, args)
```

**Explanation**

First of all, you have to understand how decorators work, because classmethod is a decorator.

Writing

```
@classmethod
def cfn(cls, *args):
    print(cls, *args)
```

is actually the same as writing

```
def cfn(cls, *args):
    print(cls, *args)
cfn = classmethod(cfn)
```

Now if you try to add an attribute to your method, do not write it as

```
@classmethod
def cfn(cls, *args):
    print(cls, *args)
cfn.val = 10
```

because it is equivalent to

```
def cfn(cls, *args):
    print(cls, *args)
cfn = classmethod(cfn)
cfn.val = 10
```

so you are adding the attribute to a **method returned by decorator**, not your actual method. The simple solution is to add the attribute to your method and **after that** decorate it:

```
def cfn(cls, *args):
    print(cls, *args)
cfn.val = 10
cfn = classmethod(cfn)
```

This way you decorate the method that already has an attribute attached and apparently decorator returns the same method object, so you don't lose your attribute.
We could all agree that this syntax is not really nice and hard to read. It is much nicer to keep the decorator syntax. You can put all the logic in a custom decorator like this:

```
class classmethod_with_custom_attribute(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        wrapped_func.val = self.val
        wrapped_func = classmethod(wrapped_func)
        return wrapped_func
```

Here we do the same, note the part where custom attribute is assigned **before** classmethod decorator call. Now we can use the decorator like this:

```
@classmethod_with_custom_attribute(val=10)
def cfn(cls, *args):
    print(cls, args)
```

Now you can call

```
App.cfn.val
```

and it will work as expected